# Changing default template for login form in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-templates

Very simple question. When using the `login_required` decorator above a view, the authentication system redirects me to whatever URL is defined in `LOGIN_URL` in settings.py, using the template found in `registration/login.html`.

**The question:** How can I define a different template name for my login form (I don't want to use the default)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`login` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login):

> If you’d prefer not to call the template `registration/login.html`, you can pass the `template_name` parameter via the extra arguments to the view in your URLconf. For example, this URLconf line would use `myapp/login.html` instead:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$',
 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
 {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),
```

Answer (score 1):

----Django 1.10--------

I changed TEMPLATE_DIR in settings to solve this problem

setting.py

```
    TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

        ],
    },
},]
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

**and place the `registration` file directory under `templates` directory!**

Comment: btw I am using a custom login